# Why is the order of the enums important when specifying circular enum values in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, enums, .net-5

I'm using enum circular reference to boil down some existing enums to a fewer values.
It works well for my issue, since its a for a transitions period, where old enum values do occur in history, but no new entries with the obsolete values will be created.

I'm not looking for an alternative approach, but I stumbled upon this strange issue where the order of the enums, will affect the the serilized value in an unexpected manner.

I have this enum:

```
    public enum CivilStatusEnum
    {
        None = 0,
        Married = 1,
        Cohabiting = Married,
        Alone = 3,
        DivorcedOrSeparated = Alone,
        WidowOrWidower = Alone,
    }
```

I assigned "DivorcedOrSeparated" = Alone (3). Now when I convert the enum to string I get the value "DivorcedOrSeparated".

```
Console.PrintLine(CivilStatusEnum.Alone.ToString());
```

Output:

```
DivorcedOrSeparated
```

I have an example code, with tests and their expected outcome. As you can see the test are failing. But If I change the order of the enums, the tests will parse.

[image]

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(CivilStatusEnum.Alone, "Alone")]
    [InlineData(CivilStatusEnum.DivorcedOrSeparated, "Alone")]
    [InlineData(CivilStatusEnum.WidowOrWidower, "Alone")]
    [InlineData(CivilStatusEnum.None, "None")]
    [InlineData(CivilStatusEnum.Married, "Married")]
    [InlineData(CivilStatusEnum.Cohabiting, "Married")]
    public void Test(CivilStatusEnum input, string expected)
    {
        var text = input.ToString();
        text.Should().Be(expected);
    }
```

I can't seem to find a rationel explanation for why the order matters for tostring and serilization.

Is this a bug in .NET 5, or am I missing something?
If this behaviour is deliberate, how does it determind which enum name will be the output of tostring?

Thank you :)

Comment: What is stored is not the enum text ("Alone"), but its value (3). So which of the values 3 did you mean? Alone, DivorcedOrSeparated, or WidowOrWidower?

Comment: As a side note: I've treated enums as "sets of text values from which one can be selected" for a long time as well. But in the end an enum is just a nice wrapper around a integral data type. And your code should rely on that underlying data type and not on their visual representation. If, for example, you cast an integral number into your enum's type. The result will look like one of the enums variants even though the actual integral number might not even be a valid variant. The enum just doesn't know how to handle this. It can be very misleading to trust an enums text representation.

Comment: I am aware that the enum is the value is the int and not the string. But we are talking about an existing system with a public API and bunch of historical data that needs to be available, so I can't just change the approach without major efford. I just wonder how it determinds which string to return, when calling ToString().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enum.ToString` performs a binary search.

Indeed, [ToString](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Enum.cs,b0c7d7f5b106cc60) calls [InternalFormat](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Enum.cs,b0c7d7f5b106cc60), which calls [GetEnumName](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Enum.cs,4f81b65c826a8626). That method performs a binary search in the array returned by EnumInfo.Values.

I assume that array is filled in increasing order of the underlying values (otherwise a binary search would not work), and in the order in which the values were declared in the source code if they are equal. That makes the result of the search dependent on the order of declaration.

To illustrate the effects of this binary search, consider these two `enum` definitions:

```cs
enum Test1 { A = 0, B = 0, C = 0 }
enum Test2 { A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, E = 0 }
```

What would be the result of `Test1.A.ToString()`? Note that the value of `Test1.A` is `0`. The binary search will first consider the element in the middle of the list, which is `B` with the value `0`. That value equals the value we are searching for, so `Test1.A.ToString()` returns `"B"`. If the value found was higher than the value being searched for, the search would continue in the lower half of the list. If the value found was lower than the value being searched for, the search would continue in the higher half of the list.

The same is true for all the constants in the enum, given they all have the same value. So, `Test1.C.ToString()` will equally return `"B"`.

Similarly, `Test2.A.ToString()` returns `"C"`, as expected.

Note however that while this behavior seems to be *predictable* in the current version of .NET, it is *undefined*, and could change in a future version.

This is not a bug in .NET 5. After all, it is impossible for both of the following to be true:

```cs
CivilStatusEnum.Alone.ToString() ==  "Alone"
CivilStatusEnum.DivorcedOrSeparated.ToString() == "DivorcedOrSeparated"
```

The reason is of course that `CivilStatusEnum.Alone == CivilStatusEnum.DivorcedOrSeparated`.

Here's what [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=net-5.0) has to say about this:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.

Comment: From my tests, the order does not seem to be determind by the order in the sourcecode, at least not in the expected manner. "Alone" is the first one declared and still all ToString(), on any of the enums with the value 3 will return "DivorcedOrSeparated". That is what puzzles me. If I reorder my enums, it will return a another value fx "WidowOrWidower" , I just can't figure out, how it derterminds which one to return. From the documentation you found it does sound like a bug, that they just choose to ignore by adding a disclaimer :)

Comment: It's not because "Alone" is the first one to appear in the source code, that "Alone" will be found. That would be the case if it was a simple linear search, but it's not.  It's a binary search. For example, you might see other results if you added more values at the end as well.

Comment: @Jeanette I have added an example to illustrate the effects of the binary search.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you're not looking for an alternative approach, but another way to do this and avoid this kind of problem is to use flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum CivilStatusEnum
{
    None = 0,
    Married = 1,
    Cohabiting = 3, //Married | 2
    Alone = 4,
    DivorcedOrSeparated = 12, //Alone | 8
    WidowOrWidower = 20, //Alone | 16
}
```

And then `ToString` will produce the right answer and you can check if some one is married or alone with the following code:

```
bool IsMarried(CivilStatusEnum e){
    return ((int)e&1) == 1;
}

bool IsAlone(CivilStatusEnum e){
    return ((int)e&4) == 4;
}
```

Comment: why do you need the e!=0 in IsAlone? if the right side of the && is true, the first will be as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GianPaolo yeah, you're right. I was thinking in another approach when I started writing that piece of code. Fixed now, thx!